# javascript onChange computation - show only one alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, alert

I didnt know how to properly name my question, but here goes.

In my html i have a "form" but not

```
 <form></form>
```

.It is just a couple of selects, radio buttons and text inputs.
I enter, check and select values and according to these values, some computation is done. This "form" is computing on every keydown, blur, change. So when I change one value it will immediately recalculate the results with new value.

I would like to alert the user, when he didnt fill any of the necessary inputs. Here is how it works now (this is in a separate .js file)

```
 function calculator() {

 // Here is code that gathers the data from html
 // and here are also some computations (many if-s)
 // The code is too long to be putted here
 }

 $(function () {
     $('select, input').on('keydown blur change', calculator);
 });
```

I tried to put a if statement inside of my calculator function:

```
function calculator() {

 // Here is code that gathers the data from html
 // and here are also some computations (many if-s)
 // The code is too long to be putted here

     if (val1 == '' && sadzba == '' && viem == '' && ...) {
         alert('You have to fill all necessary fields!')
     }

 }
```

This obviously caused, that the alert was popped every time I enter / choose new value, because at the beginning all variables are empty / with no value.
So how can I achieve, this situation: User fills in the "form" except of (for example)one value and only then will the alert pop up.

Than you.

Comment: A fiddle will really be helpful here

Comment: I am not sure i understand your problem. But, instead of checking all events under one if condition, you can check every element under their own eventListeners? and a working `jsfiddle` would be great.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to do the check on submit and return *false* if one of the fields is empty, preventing the form to be submitted.

```
$('form').on('submit', function () {
    if (val1 == '' || sadzba == '' || viem == '') {
      alert('You have to fill all necessary fields!');
      return false;
    } else { return true; }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a different event handler for the `onblur` event since that's when the cursor has left the input box. (It also prevents the event handler from firing all the time. That's a pretty expensive process and it can slow your page down)

```
$('select, input').on('blur', didTheyLeaveTheFieldEmpty);
```

Comment: Instead of `alert`ing, you should, imo, disable any submit mechanism you're implementing, leave a note by the Submit button if you have one that informs the user of all fields that should be filled. It's good UX though to highlight anomalies early on. Like changing the border color of that particular field to red with a message saying they can't leave it empty.

Comment: but there is no submit button, the idea is that the user do not have to click on any button when he wants to recalculate with new values.

Comment: That's just by the way. Are you recalculating on every keystroke so that an empty field would cause an error?

Comment: for example, if you have text input with the value of 100 and the result is for example 1000 and you change input to 200 the result will recalculate it self, but I am getting no errors.

Answer (score 0):

Hope I understood you right, you can try this:

```
function calculator(event) {
    if ( $(event.target).val().length == 0 ) {
          alert('fill the field');
    }
 }

$('select, input').on('keyup', calculator);
```

Answer (score 0):

even if you don't want a form with a submit buton you can create a button
and trigger your code on it's click

```
<input type="button" class="calculate">

 $(function () {
     $('.calculate').on('click', calculator);
 });
```